# Voting with django voting

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-voting

I'm having trouble registering a vote with registering a vote with django-voting: https://github.com/brosner/django-voting

I'm trying to technically upvote a comment object. Thus adding to it's score.

This is what I have so far:

**Template:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/comments/{{ comment.id }}/up/vote/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Thumbs up!</button>
</form>
```

**urls**

```
widget_dict = {
    'model': Comment,
    'template_object_name': 'comment',
    'allow_xmlhttprequest': True,
    }


 #users can comment on event objects, And VOTE on comments
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'event.views.index'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'event.views.detail'),
    url(r'^comments/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)/vote/?$', vote_on_object, widget_dict),
)
```

With this I get directed to a 404.

The **docs** give an example of :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from voting.views import vote_on_object
from shop.apps.products.models import Widget

widget_dict = {
    'model': Widget,
    'template_object_name': 'widget',
    'allow_xmlhttprequest': True,
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^widgets/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object, widget_dict),
)
```

Also, I can't add votes through the admin?
[image: Unable to add votes]

I have no idea what widget_dict actually is. I'm just trying to have the form post to `vote_on_object`. Has anyone successfully posted a vote? If so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo and you're forgetting a '/'

your url in the form should be `'/widgets/{{ comment.id }}/up/vote/'`
or the pattern should start with `comments`

And then the pattern, you forget a slash:

```
(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$
```

should be

```
(?P<direction>up|down|clear)/vote/?$
```

If you want to check routing, you can do from the shell

```
import re
re.match(r'^widgets/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)/vote/?$', '/comment/1/up/vote/')
```

and see it works

Comment: Changed my post to your suggestions. Thanks for pointing it out, However, it did not solve my problem. I'm still getting a 404 when I try to post a vote.

Comment: Try doing it from the shell and make sure your regex's work -- I cleaned up my response (the formatting was off) to show you how to test the url routes from the shell